# How to sshpass ssh-copy-id?

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I dont want to keep typing the passwords again and again, hence want to provide it into the command itself. How can I do it?

Currently, I'm doing like this

```
sshpass -p server_password port_number ssh-copy-id user@IP
```

It says,

```
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong? I found the net, and it was given the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must specify `port_number` like this:

```
sshpass -p server_password ssh-copy-id user@IP -p port_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the path of the remote host :
sshpass -p server_password port_number ssh-copy-id user@IP:your_path_here